# How to modify keys of nested array in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

I have an array that has some nested arrays, I would like to transform all the keys into snake case. I am trying this:

```
$data = collect($array)->keyBy(function ($value, $key) {
    return Str::snake($key);            
})->toArray();
        
return $data;
```

It is working fine, but only works for the parent array, nested arrays keep the same key:

```php
[
    "some_key" => "value",
    "some_key" => [
        "someKey" => "value",
        "someKey" => [
            "someKey" => "value"
        ]
    ]
]
```

What can I do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the helpers [`dot`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-array-dot) and [`set`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-array-set) for this:

```
$flat = Arr::dot($array);
$newArray = [];
foreach ($flat as $key => $value) {
     // You might be able to just use Str::snake($key) here. I haven't checked
    $newKey = collect(explode('.', $key))->map(fn ($part) => Str::snake($part))->join('.');
    Arr::set($newArray, $newKey, $value);
}
```